# Classify all $n$ for which there exists a right triangle with coprime integer side lengths and such that its area equals $n$ times its perimeter.

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I know a characterization of primitive pythagorean triples: A right triangle has coprime integer side lengths if and only if those side lengths are: 
\begin{align*}
m^2-k^2, \qquad 2mk, \qquad m^2+k^2
\end{align*}
for some $m,k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\gcd(m,k)=1$, $\, m>k$, and $\,m\not\equiv k$ (mod $2$). So essentially I'm looking for a classification of all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for which there exist these $m,k$ where (plugging into the area/perimeter formulas for triangles):
\begin{align*}
(m^2-k^2)mk=n(2m^2 +2mk)
\end{align*}
And then solving for $n$:
\begin{align*}
n = \frac{(m+k)(m-k)mk}{2m(m+k)} = \frac{(m-k)k}{2}
\end{align*}
Since $m\not \equiv k$ (mod $2$), $\,2 \nmid (m-k)$, and thus $k$ must be even, and $m$ odd. Set $\frac{k}{2}=c$. Maybe an answer to this problem could be that a necessary and sufficient condition for $n$ is that:
\begin{align*}
n=(m-2c)c
\end{align*}
for some $m,c \in \mathbb{N}$ where $m$ is odd, $\,m>2c$, and $\gcd(m,c)=1$. Here's my issue with this answer though - it doesn't exactly help determine if some given $n$ has the desired property or not, at least not right off the bat... For instance, if I wanted to know if there's a coprime side-length right triangle with area equaling $147$ times its perimeter... well I don't know if $147=(m-2c)c\,$ for any $m,c\in \mathbb{N}$. What else can be done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c$ be the highest power of $2$ that goes evenly into $n$, and let $m=\frac{n}{c}+2c$. Thus *every* $n$ has a corresponding $m$ and $c$.

Since this makes $k$ a power of $2$ and $m$ odd, they are coprime.

Answer (score 2):

m is odd iff m-2c is odd

gcd(m,c)=1 iff gcd(m-2c,c)=1

Therefore we can formulate our final solution as n=pc where gcd(p,c)=1 and p is odd. Ofcourse for all n, this gives us p=1 and c=n. This gives us k=2n and m=2n+1.
These are certainly coprime with m>k. And checking that they satisfy
$$\begin{align*}
(m^2-k^2)mk=n(2m^2 +2mk)
\end{align*}$$
$$\impliedby(m-k)k=2n$$
Plugging in k=2n and m=2n+1,
$$((2n+1)-(2n))(2n)=2n$$
So it seems n can be any natural number.

With side lengths, $4n+1$, $8n^2+4n+1$ and $8n^2+4n$

Answer (score 1):

We seek a formula where area/perimeter ratio = R which can be any multiple of $1/2$.
\begin{equation}
R=\frac{mk-k^2}{2}\quad\implies k=\frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2-8R}}{2}\quad\text{for}\quad \big\lceil\sqrt{8R}\big\rceil\le m \le (2R+1)
\end{equation}
The lower limit insures that $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures that $m> k$.
$$R=1\implies  \lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil=3\le m \le (2+1)=3 \qquad\land\qquad   m\in\{ 3\}\implies k\in\{ 2,1\}$$
$$F(3,2)=(5,12,13)\quad\land\quad \frac{30}{30}=1\qquad\qquad\qquad F(3,1)=(8,6,10)\quad\land\quad \frac{24}{24}=1$$
$\\$
\begin{equation}
R=3\implies  \lceil\sqrt{8*3}\rceil=5\le m \le (2*3+1)=7\\ 
 m\in\{ 5\}\implies k\in\{ 3,2\}
\qquad\land\qquad 
m\in\{ 7\}\implies k\in\{ 6.1\}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f(5,3)=(16,30,34)\quad  R=\frac{16*30/2}{16+30+34}=3\\  
f(5,2)=(21,20,29)\quad  R=\frac{21*20/2}{21+20+29}=3\\
f(7,6)=(13,84,85)\quad  R=\frac{13*84/2}{13+84+85}=3\\
f(7,1)=(48,14,50)\quad  R=\frac{48*14/2}{48+14+50}=3
\end{equation}

Note that when $m,k$ are of the same parity, the triples are not primitive, even if they are co-prime. Some claim that $k=2^n$ but a counterexample is
$R=1.5\text{ where } m\in\{4\}\implies k\in\{3,1\}$.
$$f(4,3)=(7,24,25)\quad\implies R=\frac{7*24/2}{7+24+25}=\frac{84}{56}=1.5$$
$$f(4,1)=(15,8,17) \quad\implies R=\frac{15*8/2}{15+8+17}=\frac{60}{40}=1.5$$

For your final question, using this technique, here are some triples where R=147.

$$f(35,21)=(784,1470,1666)\qquad f(35,14)=(1029,980,1421)\qquad
f(49,42)=(637,4116,4165)\qquad f(49,7)=(2352,686,2450)\qquad 
f(55,49)=(624,5390,5426)\qquad f(55,6)=(2989,660,3061)\qquad
f(101,98)=(597,19796,19805)\qquad f(101,3)=(10192,606,10210)\qquad
f(149,147)=(592,43806,43810)\qquad f(149,2)=(22197,596,22205)\qquad 
f(295,294)=(589,173460,173461)\qquad f(295,1)=(87024,590,87026)
$$